# WCF Azure Cloud Service https not working

Tags: wcf, azure, ssl, https, windows-phone

So i tried to provide a https endpoint for my wcf Azure cloud service by following this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff795779.aspx

I followed every step (using a self-signed certificate) and published the service successfully.

When i enter http://yetanothersoftware.cloudapp.net/YASCrooksNCriminalsService.svc the well-known site pops up, stating that i can create a proxy by using "svcutil.exe http://yetanothersoftware.cloudapp.net/YASCrooksNCriminalsService.svc?wsdl", which is good and works as expected.

However, when i enter https://yetanothersoftware.cloudapp.net/YASCrooksNCriminalsService.svc the same site pops up, also showing http://yetanothersoftware.cloudapp.net and so on. I imagined it should show httpS and when i try and configure my (wp 8.1) client to use the https endpoint i get a notfound exception, which makes sense if the service is not working correctly.

Does anyone have a good idea on how to get https to work? My configs look about the same as in the tutorial above. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `openssl s_client -connect mydomain.cloudapp.net:443` hangs. I suspect `mydomain.cloudapp.net` is phony. Its difficult to help when incorrect information is intentionally provided.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't think that information was needed, mydomain was just supposed to be a placeholder. I replaced it by the correct domain in the original post.